# Reconocimiento de voz en español con C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código para reconocer voz en español, el problema es que hay varias palabras las cuáles no las reconoce de forma correcta.

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeechRecognitionApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
              new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")))
            {

                recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

        static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

También he probado definir las palabras que puede reconocer, de esta forma nunca se equivoca, el inconveniente es que el número de palabras que reconoce está limitado al numero de palabras que yo defina.

```
Choices colors = new Choices();
                colors.Add(new string[] { "azul", "rojo", "verde" });

                      // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object.
                      GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
                gb.Append(colors);

                      // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
                      Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);


                // Create and load a dictation grammar.
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);
```

**¿Existe alguna forma de reconocer varias palabras sin que se equivoque y sin que se vea limitado por las palabras definidas?**

Comment: Hasta donde se, y por experiencia, no se puede mejorar mucho el reconocimiento de voz, es mas un tema de buena pronunciación, como bien dices, la manera mas "efectiva" es creando un diccionario propio, pero viéndose limitado. Hablo desde la experiencia en windows 7, no se que tal se comporte esa librería en windows 10 con la implementación de cortana y mejora del sistema de reconocimiento de voz.

Comment: Date una vuelta por este sitio de Microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/speech

Comment: Creo que Cortana tiene buen reconocimiento, sin embargo necesita conexión a Internet.

Comment: @AlejandroMedina gracias, revisaré el enlace.

Comment: La mejor forma de reconocimiento de voz se consigue actualmente con redes neuronales, el problema de éstas es que hay que entrenarlas con muchos tipos diferentes de voz y muchas palabras para que consigan un % bajo de error. Recuerdo hace unos 20 años existía un software (ahora mismo no recuerdo el nombre), que antes de usarlo te hacía leer partes del Quijote, luego de unos 30 minutos de entrenamiento, funcionaba muy bien.

Comment: @FrEqDe tal como te mencionan los comentarios anteriores la mejor solución seria  que definas un diccionario de palabras ya que la de por defecto es muy limitada, lo digo por experiencia propia. Lo otro seria conectarlo como menciona tracker aun proyecto que sea entrenado con las palabras formando una base datos  y que te de el input que necesitas.

Comment: Lo mas facil es un diccionario de palabras extenso, o limitar tu software a palabras q solo el usuario utilizara

Comment: +1 por que me interesa saber quien tiene una solucion para esto

Comment: @FrEqDe has intentado usar un [DictationGrammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx) , en vez de un `Grammar` (que es para comando y control) ?  algo como esto: `using (
      SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
      new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")))
{
   DictationGrammar dg = new DictationGrammar();

   recognizer.LoadGrammar(dg);

   recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disculpen si esto no califica como respuesta pero es muy largo para ser un comentario.
He tenido que lidiar con el mismo problema en el pasado y por un tiempo largo, de lo cual puedo dar cuenta de lo siguiente:
**No hay algo que programaticamente puedas hacer para mejorar el funcionamiento del motor de reoconocimiento de voz**, las opciones normalmente se ven limitadas a:
 - 1 Entrenarlo a que reconozca mejor tu voz.
 - 2 Tener un micrófono que reduzca la cantidad de ruido que recibe para poder obtener una mejor lectura.
 De todas formas el funcionamiento nunca mejorara del 80% es lo mismo para los distintos sistemas de reconocimiento del habla como [sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/). **Sirven muy bien para una lista de comandos acotados pero no para transcribir un discurso entero**.
Una alternativa es utilizar algun reconocimiento de habla online que tome provecho de las redes neuronales, como usuario puedo decir que son mucho mas eficaces pero realmente nunca he desarrollado una aplicacion con ellas:
 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/
 - https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/
La contra es claro, que requieren de acceso a internet y que tanto la de google como la de microsoft son pagas.
Tambien existe el proyecto de [mozilla deepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech)  que utiliza redes neuronales y no es necesario conectarlo a internet.